# BlueZ: Using LE Data Packet Length Extension from the command line

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, l2cap

One of the main features of Bluetooth 4.2 was LE Data Length Packet Length Extension, which allowed Bluetooth devices to increase the LE packet from 27 octets to 251 octets, therefore significantly improving throughput and battery life. Is there a command in BlueZ that allows me to enable this feature? I'd like to be able to send data between two LE devices using larger data packets.

Comment: clutching at straws here but did you ever get anywhere with this?